# Google Apps Scripts interfering with each other

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a file where I have saved multiple scripts inside the same project. When I try to run one of the scripts, it generates the error message below that refers to another script.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
(anonymous) @ Seller Assistant.gs:3
```

I am trying to understand how I can avoid this.

The script I am running is completely independent of the script "Seller Assistant" (referenced above) from which the error is coming from. I did not call the "Seller Assistant" script anywhere in the script I am running so I am confused why an error from that script is being generated.

The code blocks of the two scripts are relatively long so I have added them to the doc below:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hRX0FW5c8nmsFD2xIsLGBKT0B09Q4OPcK2wZip69Cak/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your code directly into your question. [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Just wondering, have you checked if  App Script is attempting to run the right function? (at the top drop-down)? I asked, 'cause just last week I had quite a buggy behavior where App Script was trying to call a function from a different script within the same project.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know "Seller Assistant" from your question, when I saw the script of your provided Document, it seems that you are using the global variables. I'm worried whether these variables might be related to your current issue. Or, from your error message, the Class Sheet object for `getRange` might be null. How about them?

Comment: Thank you for including a link to your spreadsheet. However your question must stand on its own, and independent of your spreadsheet (which may not be accessible at some point in the future). You should not assume that users can/will/should open your spreadsheet to better understand your question. Your code should be included **in text** in the body of your question. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)